# Solve for $x$: $1024 = 2(3x+7)^{3/2}$

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone show me how to solve this problem step by step? I keep trying and get non-numerical answers. $x$ should be a whole number.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just take it step-by-step, doing the same thing to both sides. To begin with, we can divide both sides by $2$, yielding $512 = (3x+7)^{3/2}$.

Comment: Then note that $(3x+7)^{3/2}=\left(\sqrt{3x+7}\right)^3$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
1024 = 2 ( 3x+7) ^ {\frac{3}{2}} \\
\iff 512 = ( 3x+7) ^ {1.5}  \\
\iff 2^9= (3x+7) ^ {\frac{3}{2}}  \\
\iff 2^6 * 2^3 = (3x+7) ^ {1.5} = 64^{1.5}  \\
\iff 64 = 3x+7\\
\iff 57 = 3x \\
\iff 19 = x
$$

Can you follow these steps?